# how to generate thumbnail image from embed url of different site's?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I want to generate thumbnail images from Video's embed url without downloading video but using C# code or javascript.
I want to get thumbnail image from url. It is may be from youtube, dailymotion, vimeo etc..

Comment: What you have tried so far? Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800681/how-to-show-images-from-a-video-as-preview-for-playlist)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show Images from a video as preview for playlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800681/how-to-show-images-from-a-video-as-preview-for-playlist)

Answer (score 2):

Different video sharing website gives different way to get/display thumbnail images. So you should handle different website videos accordingly to identify whether it from YouTube, Vimeo or else.

As YouTube gives you facility where you can render thumbnail images using URL

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/video-id/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/video-id/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/video-id/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/video-id>/3.jpg
```

Here you will need to just get `video-id` instead of rendering whole video.

---

For the Vimeo, it provides api to get information of video by it's id.

```
http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/video-id.output
```

Where `video-id` is id of the video you want information for.
`output` Specify the output type. They offer `JSON`, `PHP`, and `XML` formats. [Here you can find docs](https://developer.vimeo.com/api#video-request)

Hope this helps!

Comment: your answer is just for yotube or vimeo but my requirement is I need to thumbnail from any video site's embed url i can not specify in code it is for youtube or vimeo or dailymotion i can not make it static

Comment: Is there out there a general library that downloads video thumbnails for any arbitrary video url?